# Styling/JS not applied to element with ngAfterViewInit? - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a word-clock where the numbers are represented with words and I also wanted the text to be different font sizes depending on the size of the containing div.

Numbers are converted to text with '[**number-to-words**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words)', and varying the size of fonts works with '[angular-fittext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-fittext)' however, the fitText only works for non-changing variable values it appears.

Whenever I apply it to my continuously updating variables like the seconds of the clock, it does not affect it.

Could somebody shed some light on my error? Perhaps because I am rendering the clock variables in the **ngAfterViewInit** function and not one that detects changes?

Here is my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clock-app) with a non-changing variable and a changing variable

Comment: And what's the issue in your blitz ?

Comment: That the `seconds` dont get resized by the `fittext` directive I believe

Comment: The `fittext` directive doesn't know when it needs to update. The way around this is to bind your value using `[(ngModel)]`, like `<p fittext [(ngModel)]="seconds" [delay]="0"></p>` (although the size recalculation seems a little off...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [ngModel], because the {{xxx}} will send no event to the element.

See:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clock-app-ykzksi?embed=1&file=src/app/components/clock/clock.component.html

~

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the advice @Mark :-)